# Paste with newline using adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, clipboard

I am trying this:

```
service call clipboard 2 i32 1 i32 18 s16 Line1\nLine2
```

also tried

```
service call clipboard 2 i32 1 i32 18 s16 Line1\rLine2
```

But it gives me `Line1nLine2` and `Line1rLine2`. How do I send newline?

Comment: Is it possible to use cat? ```cat | adb shell "service call clipboard 2 i32 1 i32 18 s16"```

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary alternative:

```
telnet localhost 5554
sms send 5554 Line1\nLine2
```

and can copy from there.